# Code does not work if I replace something with a variable, containing the same content

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, replace

I was doing the following task: given a 2D grid of size m x n and an integer k. You need to shift the grid k times.

[image: This shows the task in a picture]

So came up with the following code which works completely fine:

```
"""
:type grid: List[List[int]]
:type k: int
:rtype: List[List[int]]
"""
class Solution(object):
    def shiftGrid(self, grid, k):
        #convert grid into 1D list conv
        conv = sum(grid, [])
        
        #pre-calculating length of list to save runtime
        length = len(conv)
        
        #pre-calculating last element of list to save runtime
        last = length-1
        
        # calculate the number of grids so we can separate them again later
        grid_counter = length/len(grid)
        
        #k-times: insert last item from list conv to beginning and than delete the last item
        for i in range(k):
            conv.insert(0, conv[(len(conv)-1)])
            del conv[len(conv)-1]
            
        #reconvert 1D list conv to a 2D list and return it
        return [conv[i:i+grid_counter] for i in xrange(0, len(conv), grid_counter)]
```

As you can see the for-loop operates with `len(conv)-1` which I wanted to replace to save runtime. So I pre-calculated it above.
But as soon as I replace `len(conv)-1` with `last` the code does not work anymore because it gives the wrong output. So I went a step back and only replaced `len(conv)` with `length` but the problem remains. Even if I precalculate `last` and `length` inside the for-loop it does not work.

Is there something I missed or made wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
conv.insert(0, conv[(len(conv)-1)])
del conv[len(conv)-1]
```

In the second line, you're deleting right after doing an insert. Because you just added an element in the previous line, `len(conv)-1` in the delete line is not the same as `last`; it would be one more. You would have to put the variable between these lines to do what you're trying to do.

I'll note though, you have this comment:

```
#pre-callculating last element of list to save runtime
```

Calculating `len(conv)-1` is incredibly fast. `len` is O(1); the runtime isn't dependant on the length of the list. I would not use a variable for performance reasons here. I would expect essentially no gain.

Comment: Ah ok thank you very much it worked. Is there anything else I could change on my code to save runtime?

Comment: @szoeke `sum(grid, [])` would require creating some temporary lists. Calling `extend` in a loop over `grid` would likely be faster. Calling `insert(0,` is super slow too. Inserting into the front of a list requires shifting all the other elements down first to make room in the array. If you need front inserts, `import dequeue`, then `appendleft` on it instead.